.Net 8 x86 based Projects always refer the x64 based dotnet SDK libraries
I have created a simple console App which is implicitly using Native Libraries via DLLImport, so I have set my application target to x86 platform. But implicit reference of dotnet sdk libraries are still referring from below path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\8.0.0\ref\net8.0". It was expected the target frameworks should be switched to "C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\8.0.0\ref\net8.0" when I have set Platform target as "x86". Is there any explicit configuration required to be set by project to be referred from Program Files(x86) location?
Project target to x86 Platform
It was expected those .NET SDK libraries are referred from the Program Files(x86) location so it work as expected on x86 platform with Native libraries.

The dlls in these 2 folders are identical, you don't need to worry about it.
